# Hazelcast sort IMap (Scala)

Tags: scala, sorting, dictionary, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast IMap[String,Any] in my application. When printing the map it should be sorted by the keys.

Is there a nice way to sort the IMap by key (other than sort the keys locally and print by the sorted keys)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/remeniuk/hazelcast-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IMap` extends the regular `java.util.Map` you could use a [`scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap), which is always sorted by keys.

```
println(TreeMap() ++ imap)
```

This obviously does not come for free because you need to iterate over the `IMap` and sort it each time you want to print it.

Comment: This sorts the map locally, which is the opposite of what was asked.